# Easiest way to subtract associated with one factor level from values associated with all other factor levels

Tags: r, plyr

I've got a dataframe containing rates for 'live' treatments and rates for 'killed' treatments. I'd like to subtract the killed treatments from the live ones:

```
df <- data.frame(id1=gl(2, 3, labels=c("a", "b")),
                 id2=rep(gl(3, 1, labels=c("live1", "live2", "killed")), 2), 
                 y=c(10, 10, 1, 12, 12, 2),
                 otherFactor = gl(3, 2))
```

I'd like to subtract the values of `y` for which `id2=="killed"` from all the other values of `y`, separated by the levels of id1, while preserving `otherFactor`. I would end up with

```
id1    id2   y otherFactor
  a  live1   9           1
  a  live2   9           1
  b  live1  10           2
  b  live2  10           3
```

This almost works:

```
df_minusKill <- ddply(df, .(id1), function(x) x$y[x$id2!="killed"] - x$y[x$id2=="killed"])
names(df_minusKill) <- c("id1", "live1", "live2")
df_minusKill_melt <- melt(df_minusKill, measure.var=c("live1", "live2"))
```

except that you lose the values of otherFactor. Maybe I could use `merge` to put the values of `otherFactor` back in, but in reality I have about a dozen "otherFactor" columns, so it would be less cumbersome to just keep them in there automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df2 <- ddply(df, .(id1), transform, y = y-y[id2=="killed"])
df2[-which(df2$id2=="killed"),]
  id1   id2  y otherFactor
1   a live1  9           1
2   a live2  9           1
4   b live1 10           2
5   b live2 10           3
```

Answer (score 2):

The `by` function can process sections of dataframe separately by factors (or you could use `lapply(split(df , ...))`:

```
>  by(df, df$id1, FUN= function(x) x[['y']]-x[ x$id2=="killed", "y"] )
df$id1: a
[1] 9 9 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$id1: b
[1] 10 10  0
> unlist( by(df, df$id1, FUN= function(x) x[['y']]-x[ x$id2=="killed", "y"] ) )
a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 
 9  9  0 10 10  0
```

You could assign this to a column in df and subset out the rows with `id2` not equal to 'killing'.